# How can I resize my Blender models when importing to Unity?

Tags: unity, models, scale, importing

I made a 3D model in Blender, but when put it in my Unity project and add an FPS-camera the camera is bigger then my model. I used the measurements of Blender (that one cube is 1 meter in Unity).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Take care about unity import settings...

If you click on your model in unity you will see scale factor among the parameters. Take care the value is correct to fit your needs.